# Magento Migration - Always 404

Tags: web-server, migration, http-status-code-404, magento

I just cant get Magento running on a new server. I followed these [Instructions](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/moving_magento_to_another_server) exactly, I tried both methods.
When I open the website, it just gives me the Magento `404 "Page not Found"` page. I do not get any errors in my nginx error log either.
How can I fix that? How could I enable some Magento logging, without having access to the admin panel?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

So, Nginx doesn't deal with PHP itself, you must be farming that out to something like PHP-FCGI, does that show any errors in it's logfile?

You need to make sure that you've configured PHP-FPM properly as well to read from the correct document root. Probably go through some instructions like [these](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2011/nginx-and-php-fpm-configuration-and-optimizing-tips-and-tricks/) and make sure you've got everything properly configured.

This isn't going to be a Magento problem, but a problem with the configuration of either your webserver or your PHP server.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at this. However, my Magento config for nginx works perfectly with other magento installs.

Comment: there are no errors in the php logfile. Do note that it is no server 404 but a magento 404 response. It could actually be Magento-related.

Comment: Magento should have a full report about the issue in it's var/reports folder.

Answer (score 0):

If your new server is on a different domain, you need to change the base URLs in the web area of the Magento Admin panel.

> System > Configuration > General > Web

Answer (score 0):

Magento Migration is always 404 because Magento uses the “vendor” directory and “root” directory to send files to the client. So, if you upgrade to Magento 1.7, need to create a directory “mydomainname.com/web/vendor”, once created, you can upload the files of Magento 2.0 to this directory, or you can simply upload the files to the root directory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).